# Animating the selection of UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, uiview, uibutton

Good Moscow evening to everyone!

I'm still unfamiliar with principles of iPhone animation (btw, does anybody know a big and nice tutorial on this?), but in my project I want to do button "highlighted-not highlighted" flicker to notify the user that its label has changed.

This code doesn't do anything (it's just a fragment of flicker animation):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.5]; 

[button setHighlighted: YES];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

And this one highlights the button, but does not do it in an animated form:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.5]; 

[button setSelected: YES];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Can anyone help me and say:

1. What's wrong with this code?
2. What would fix the problem?

----------------------------------- UPDATE ------------------------------

I tried that kind of code, but it doesn't work either:

```
// ------------------------
// --- animation ----------
// ------------------------

- (void)animateIn
{
[UIView beginAnimations: @"animateIn" context:nil]; 
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.2];

[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)]; 

[control setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)animateOut
{
[UIView beginAnimations: @"animateOut" context:nil];    
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.2];

[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)]; 

[control setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

[UIView commitAnimations];
}


- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context
{
if([animationID isEqualToString: @"animateIn"])
{
    [self animateOut];
    return;
}
else if ([animationID isEqualToString: @"animateOut"])
{
    cycleCount++;

    if(cycleCount < 3)
        [self animateIn];
    else
        cycleCount = 0;

    return;
}
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//isFlickerOn is declared in .h file as BOOL isFlickerOn;
//flickerTimer is declared in .h file as NSTimer *flickerTimer;
//flickerCount is declared in .h file as int flickerCount; 
//control is a UILabel, UIButton background color is really hard to notice
//especially the roundedRect UIButton, so I just flickered a UILabel's textColor

-(void)flickerOn {
    if (flickerCount < 5) 
    {
    flickerCount++;
         if (!isFlickerOn)
        {
            [control setTextColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
            isFlickerOn = YES;
        } 
        else
        {
            [control setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
            isFlickerOn = NO;   
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        [flickerTimer invalidate];
    }
}


-(void)flickerAnimation {
    flickerCount = 0;
    flickerTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.3f target:self selector:@selector(flickerOn) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thank you JustinXXVII, it seems to be working. I've already did it the way like this!

Answer (score 1):

Not *all* attributes of a UIView are animatable - and I do not believe "highlighted" or "selected" are.

Typically, it's usable for non-boolean values, like "center", "alpha", "frame" and "bounds".

Try tweaking the alpha instead, and you'll see it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a callback method that executes when the first animation finishes.  You use that callback to do create a deselected animation.  Keep in mind that there is no gradual "selection state" like there is for transparency.  You have to use the

```
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animateIn" context:NULL];
```

From Apple's docs:

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {
```

Your method must take the following arguments:

animationID

An NSString containing an optional application-supplied identifier. This is the identifier that is passed to the beginAnimations:context: method. This argument can be nil.

finished

An NSNumber object containing a Boolean value. The value is YES if the animation ran to completion before it stopped or NO if it did not.

context

An optional application-supplied context. This is the context data passed to the beginAnimations:context: method. This argument can be nil.

When the animation is finished, the callback animationDidStop is called and passed in the string @"animateIn".  You can use that method to check which animation was called and handle that there.

Comment: I tried that, but it just didn't work. Looks like the method "animationDidStop" is called before the animation is performed. No changes are visible. Please look at the updated post.

Comment: That code looks perfect, but the [UIColor whiteColor] and +blackColor may not be "animateable".  If you're just interested in "flickering" then that's not really an "animation."  You'd be better suited to an NSTimer that changes a color.  I'll add a new answer for that scenario.  In your animation blocks, try changing the alpha of your control in animateOut to 0.0f.  Change it to 1.0f in animateIn.  Change the duration to 0.3f and it might be more distinct, as well.